# How can I FTP many files I have listed in a TXT?

Tags: bash, upload, ftp

I have a list of files inside a TXT file that I need to upload to my FTP. Is there any Windows  Bat file or Linux shell script that will process it?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

cat ftp_filelist | xargs --max-lines=1 ncftpput -u user -p pass ftp_host /remote/path

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wput command.

The syntax is somewhat like this
wput -i [name of the file.txt]
Go through this link
http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html

It works for linux.With this it will upload all the URLs given in the text file onto your ftp server one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Jason Faulkners' batch script about which he wrote [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/50359/upload-files-to-an-ftp-site-via-a-batch-script/).